# Unified route transition in nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt3, vue-transitions

How can we add route transition to irrespective of page or layout change

I'm aware that nuxt provides page and layout transitions but the layouts remain static when the page changes

Expected behaviour: the whole webpage animates when route changes similar to what would happen in vue router when it is surrounded by transition element.